# Make every object inside of screen fit and show fully

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode7, viewcontroller

Ive got buttons, text fields, labels, check boxes, and i see in other apps they fit, but in mine for some reason they don't. I just want them to be in the same place as I put them in the viewcontoller when they run. They either move around or get all pushed together. How do I make every object I put into a view controller fit the way I want?

Comment: Learn how to use auto layout buddy.

Comment: @SamB tried it, only shows half the screen.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by shows half a screen. Are you sure you have the correct launch images set? There must be something wrong with your layout constraints in storyboard. Just a guess since I have no idea what you are seeing

Comment: What its supposed to look like http://i.stack.imgur.com/xs688.png

Comment: what it looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Ugq.png @SamB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) will help you get started.